# Jquery Bootstrap UI - External Modal popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a function that will create an confirm delete message on any link or button with the class of "delete", inside a bootstrap modal. I currently have this code to create a regular confirm dialog:

```
'init_confirm_delete' : function(){
    $('a.delete,button.delete').live('click',function(e){
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

},
```

That works fine. Below is my new code trying to integrate bootstrap UI:

```
    'init_confirm_delete' : function(){
    $('a.delete,button.delete').click(function () {
        $('#delete-confirm').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
    $("delete-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("Delete");
            },
        }
    })      
},
```

Any ideas fellow coders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a mistake and that is

```
$("delete-confirm").dialog({ ... }); // missing # for id selector
```

should be

```
$("#delete-confirm").dialog({ ... });
```